# Background color only displays above the fold

Tags: html, css

Try to access acetheinterview.co on your mobile phone and go to page 2. You will see that the part of the screen you see when you land on the page has a background color but when you start to scroll it becomes white and you cannot see the last part of my content.

Any ideas how to fix?

```css
     .page {
          display:none;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
          padding-top: 0px;
          padding-bottom: 0px;
        }
        
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        
             body {
               width: 100vw;
               height: 100vh;
               margin: 0;
               font-family: "Helvetica Neue" !important;
             }
        
             html {
                margin: 0;
             }
        
            .jumbotron {
              height:100%;
              background: url('hero-bg-v1.jpg');
              text-align: center;
              margin: 0 !important;
            }
        
            h1 {
              color: #FFFFFF !important;
              font-size: 45px !important;
              padding-top: 10%;
              font-weight: 500;
              line-height: 50px;
              letter-spacing: 0.8px;
            }
        
            h2 {
              color: #FFFFFF !important;
              font-size: 20px !important;
              font-weight: 400;
              letter-spacing: 0.8px;
              padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        
            #page1 {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-color: #7DBB91;
            }
        
            #page2 {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-color: #8BCBCA; 
            }
        
            #page3 {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-color: #C384C5;
            }
        
            #page4 {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-color: #7C8DF5;
            }
        
            #page5 {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-color: #E96C6C;
              text-align: center;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <h1 class="advice">ADVICE #1</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <p class="quote">Always, always research the company you are interviewing with. What is their core product?
                    What other opportunities are they pursuing? What are the challenges they are facing?
                  </p>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-md sales-cta" id="previousbuttonpage1">Previous</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-md sales-cta" id="nextbuttonpage1">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 text-center hidden-xs">
                  <%= image_tag("quote.png", width: "250", height: "170")  %>
                  <h2 class="author">Girl</h2>
                  <h3 class="job-title">Product Manager</h3>
                  <h4 class="company">Google</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
              <div class="author-picture" id="joe">
                <%= image_tag("joe-zadeh.png")  %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: This happens on Safari iOS

Comment: Is it the same behavior as looking at it in a very small browser on a pc?
I have never used the vh for size yet, but try changing that to 100% for the body element (so  height: 100vh; to height:100%;)

Comment: Or use `min-height;100vh`

Comment: Why does your page contain two nested `<body>` elements? That is not how HTML works.

Answer (score 0):

As I guess this is the problem:

```
body { height: 100vh;}
```

100vh limits the heigh to the viewport height. Change this to `height:100%` or `min-height:100vh;` as Paulie_D suggested